# GitLab-KAS service failing due to invalid GitLabCF.Address in GitLab Community Edition

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce

I'm encountering an issue with GitLab's Kubernetes Agent Server (GitLab-KAS) on my DigitalOcean droplet running GitLab-CE.

Despite attempts to restart and reconfigure GitLab, the GitLab-KAS service remains down, causing a failure in my GitLab instance.

I've also made several modifications to the `gitlab.rb` configuration file but with no success.

**Goal:**
Can anyone suggest how to troubleshoot and resolve the GitLab-KAS service failure on my DigitalOcean droplet to get my GitLab up and running for everyone else?

**Current Status:**
When I run sudo `gitlab-ctl status`, I get the following output:

> down: gitlab-kas: 0s, normally up, want up

**Attempts made:**

- I tried **disabling** `GitLab-KAS` by setting ***gitlab_kas['enable'] = false*** in gitlab.rb.

While this prevents the service from starting and does not show up in gitlab-ctl status, it doesn't resolve the issue, and I don't receive any response in the UI.

- I also attempted to configure the external URL for GitLab-KAS by adding ***gitlab_kas_external_url "wss://gitlab.company.com/-/kubernetes-agent/"***, but GitLab-KAS remains down.
- Additionally, I tried **enabling** GitLab-KAS with the following configurations in gitlab.rb:
  ***gitlab_kas['internal_api_listen_network'] = 'unix'
  gitlab_kas['internal_api_listen_address'] = '/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-kas/sockets/internal-api.socket'
  gitlab_kas['private_api_listen_network'] = 'unix'
  gitlab_kas['private_api_listen_address'] = '/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-kas/sockets/private-api.socket'
  gitlab_kas['env'] = {
  'SSL_CERT_DIR' => "/opt/gitlab/embedded/ssl/certs/",
  'OWN_PRIVATE_API_URL' => 'unix:///var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-kas/sockets/private-api.socket'
  }***

However, this also didn't resolve the issue.